# remove some data from many to many result

Tags: mysql, many-to-many

I have issue with my many to many database .

I have simple blog system

post | 
category |
post_has_category

when I used join to select the posts has not in category "3" ,it's filed (3 is example  entry )

because in my database store post category like this

post(id):1

category(id):3

post_has_category:

post_id category_id

1       3

1       4

after I select the post don'n in cat 3 , the post 1 is selected but I don't want it , because it's belongs to cat 3 in other row ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use a subquery to identify all `post_id` in which a `category_id` of 3 appeared.  Then, we can left join the original table to this subquery and retain only those `post_id` which did not match to any of the offending ones in the subquery.

```
SELECT p1.*
FROM posts p1
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT DISTINCT post_id
    FROM posts
    WHERE category_id = 3
) p2
    ON p1.post_id = p2.post_id
WHERE p2.post_id IS NULL
```

Note that `DISTINCT` in the subquery should be unnecessary if a given `post_id` can only be associated with a given `category_id` once.

Comment: very nice let I check it out then I mark correct for your answer thank you